# Good introduction to constructive mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, constructive-mathematics

I am looking for a good introduction to constructive mathematics:

- it should introduce the central motivation of constructive mathematics. (or motivations if there are multiple distinct but important motivations for it)
- it should provide some examples of theorems that are true (false) in classical mathematics, but false (true) in constructive mathematics. And with proofs of course.
- it should ideally also address both the interests of a mathematician and of a logician.
- it should outline maybe some ways in which constructive mathematics gives us insights, or can be implied in some way, that classical mathematics cannot.
- it should be clearly written of course.

I am not sure if this could be captured in an article rather than a book, but I am open to both an article and a book.

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer since I'm not sure this is quite what you're looking for, but you may be interested in the book [Varieties of constructive mathematics](https://www.amazon.com/Varieties-Constructive-Mathematics-Mathematical-Society/dp/0521318025).

Comment: ["The Continuum: A Constructive Approach to Basic Concepts of Real Analysis"](https://www.amazon.com/Continuum-Constructive-Approach-Concepts-Monographs/dp/3834800406/) by Rudolf Taschner. I don't know the book (but I ordered it today) and so I don't know if it mets your criteria. But I attended lectues of Taschner in the 1980s and know some of his german books (that are currently ou of print) and therefore want to recommend the books of the author. [Here](https://www.amazon.de/Continuum-Constructive-Approach-Concepts-Monographs/dp/3834800406) the book is on stock.

Comment: This doesn't address your concerns, but Troelstra's [relatively brief article on the history of constructivism](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.2581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) might serve as an overview of the areas considered. In my experience, when people talk of constructive or even intuitionistic logic, they usually mean systems compatible with classical logic, *not* systems with anti-classical axioms. It can never be the case that these systems refute a classical theorem. Admittedly, the ability to adopt anti-classical axioms is one of the benefits of constructivism.

Comment: @derekElkins, thank you. Do you mean by anti-classical axioms, axioms that imply propositions that are false in classical mathematics? Indeed i did not know about that but I am interested. What I know about constructive mathematics is majnly that the law of the excluded middle no longer holds. I will read the article thank you.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Yes, anti-classical axioms are axioms that are inconsistent (in the context of constructive logic) with classical logic, i.e. the law of the excluded middle. For example, that all functions are continuous in Brouwer's intuitionism, or all functions are computable in constructive recursive mathematics, or the Kock-Lawvere axiom in synthetic differential geometry.